# How to get a value from textarea within modal popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is this http://jsfiddle.net/WV5e7/ modal which I copy/pasted and currently working with right now.

here is the code: 
js

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#textareaID').focus();
})
```

html:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg launch-modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <textarea id="textareaID" class="form-control"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

It works as seen in the demo, but when someone hits 'save changes' I can't seem to get the value of the text area inside it.

I did

```
$('#textareaID').val();
```

But, but there is not value, since it is trying to get the value before the save changes button is clicked.

So, I currently do not know how to get the value  of the text submited using jquery

Comment: @Kinduser sorry, typo

Comment: @user7342807 please share your code with fixed code and reproduce the same problem

Comment: @gurvinder372 Its fixed! I just need to get the value of the textarea

Comment: In that case the answer provided by me isn't invalid, since that is the answer to your question only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
$("#myModal").find('#textareaID').val();
```

Comment: Same issue i was facing and it worked as expected. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
$('#textareaID').value();
```

with

```
$('#textareaID').val();
```

Comment: That was a typo, I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

here is an example how to take out the value. https://jsfiddle.net/WV5e7/315/ and see if that works for you

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#textareaID').focus();
  $('.btn.btn-primary').click( function () {
    alert($('#textareaID').val());
  });
})
```

Comment: This helped, but if I assign the value to variable instead of alert, then the variable looses it outside the jquery function

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary save-data">Save changes</button>

$('.save-data').on('click', function(){
    var getVal = $('#textareaID').val();
  if(getVal != '') {
    alert(getVal);
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
  } else {
    alert('textarea is required.');
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, add an class to "Save Changes" button. Because you need handle click event.

And use this code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary save">Save changes</button>

$(".save").on("click", function() {
    console.log($("#textareaID").val())
})
```

Comment: I found out the issue. It seems whatever variable holds the value of my textarea is not detected outside the $('.').click(function(){ ..here.. });